# parsing sip using pjsip

Tags: parsing, sip, pjsip

does any one has experience in using pjsip ? I'm trying to parse SIP message without success.
Even the simplest program does not work. Here is the code http://pastebin.com/gVTC3zRw
it gives my "Segmentation fault". Please help. I'm trying to make it work for 2 day now...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I now know what is wrong. Before calling pjsip_parse_msg the endpoint must be initialized :)

Comment: Actually no. You does not initialize endpoint before parsing. Endpoint is UA agemt level object. You working without endpoint in there.